# closure compilation ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS complaining about use of this

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a `Gruntfile.js` as below with **closure compiler config**,

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     'closure-compiler': {
         jstracker: {
              closurePath: '/usr/local/',
              js: [
                'src/js/banner.js',
                'src/js/lib/json.js',
                'src/js/lib/jstz.js',
                'src/js/init.js',
                'src/js/helpers.js',
                'src/js/lib/sha1.js',
                'src/js/lib/murmur.js',
                'src/js/lib/base64.js',
                'src/js/tracker.js',
                'src/js/prayagupd.js',
                'src/js/constructor.js'
               ],
              jsOutputFile: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js',
              options: {
                      compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIIZATIONS',
                      warning_level:"DEFAULT",
                      language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT'
               }
          }
    },

    qunit: {
        files: ['tests/**/*.html']
    },
    jshint: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'tests/*.js'],
        options: {
            // options here to override JSHint defaults
            globals: {
                jQuery: true,
                console: true,
                module: true,
                document: true
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'qunit']
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-compiler');

grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'closure-compiler', 'qunit']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'closure-compiler', 'qunit']);
```

};

When I execute `grunt` to generate minified js, I see minified version at `target` folder,

```
$ ls -lh dist/
total 44K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 prayagupd prayagupd  27K Jul  6 16:34 prayagupd.min.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 prayagupd prayagupd  514 Jul  6 16:34 prayagupd.min.js.report.txt
```

But with following 4 warnings all pointing to use of `this`, that later pops up as error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON2 is not defined`) while using in browser.

```
src/js/lib/json.js:26: WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object
if (!this.JSON2) {
     ^
src/js/lib/json.js:27: WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object
    this.JSON2 = {};
    ^
src/js/leakers.js:1995: WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object
            this.setContextProperty("leaksId", leaksId);
            ^
src/js/leakers.js:2002: WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object
            this.setContextProperty("userId", userId);
            ^
0 error(s), 4 warning(s)
```

`SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` level works fine though.

### Offending source codes

```
//src/js/lib/json.js:26
// Create a JSON object only if one does not already exist. We create the
// methods in a closure to avoid creating global variables.
if (!this.JSON2) {
    this.JSON2 = {};
}
```

**and,**

```
   //src/js/leakers.js

   /**
    * Set context properties, properties which are used with every event
    */
    setContextProperty: function(name, value) {
        context[name] = value;
    },

    /**
    * Set leaks ID
    */
    setLeakesId: function(leakesId) {
        this.setContextProperty("leakesId", leakesId);
    },

    /**
    * Set user ID
    */
    setUserId: function(userId){
        this.setContextProperty("userId", userId);
    }
```

### Two things I need help to fix;

1) ask closure to ignore `this`, which doesn't seem possible under `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

**or**

2) Find ways to replace `this` to and get working.

Comment: Could you please post the offending source code?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is basically warning that you are using "this" in a way that it is unsure about (you may be accidentally be using the global this) and maybe incompatible with advanced compilation.   You want to verify that that the "this" value is going to be correct and indicate that to the compiler by using a @this annotation.

This warning is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref